# Do-While Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucles, while

Quería consultar por qué al indicar un valor tipo **string**, en este caso '10' como condición dentro de este bucle, funciona correctamente.

A nivel conceptual, ¿qué está pasando?

```
do {
    console.log(valorInicializado);
    valorInicializado++;
} while(valorInicializado < '10');
```

Solo eso, muchas gracias.

Comment: javascript es un poco curioso y me puedo equivocar en lo que diga, pero... por que compararías un entero con un string?

Comment: No, solo estaba viendo unos viejos ejercicios y me topé con que en lugar de ser un type number, estaba como string. Ejecuté el script y funcionó bien. Me llamó la atención eso.

Comment: Ocurren conversiones automáticas dependientes del operador.

Comment: como `valorInicializado` es un number, al usar el operador de comparación automáticamente  hace un parse a number la cadena, si es caso no lo pueda convertir devolvería un NaN, que al ser comparado con cualquier numero te devolvería false.

Comment: Para ser mas preciso, se llama [*Coerción*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion).

Comment: Si , de hecho si lees lo que te devuelve la consola notaras que el primer valor viene vacio  `<empty string>`, solo desde el segundo ciclo devuelve un numero.

Comment: @Sal es una pregunta interesante, si es posible se agradece una respuesta de tu parte que arroje luz sobre este tema.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Entre las *"curiosidades"* de Javascript, destaca que no es un lenguaje tipado, es decir, puedes declarar una variable asignando un valor numérico y, después, cambiar a cadena u otro tipo de datos.

Es por eso que los operadores tratarán de convertir los elementos involucrados para que todos tengan el mismo tipo, excepto cuando se usan [operadores de comparación estricta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

En el caso de *mayor que* y *menor que*, se usa un [algoritmo abstracto de comparación relacional](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) que, de acuerdo al [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than), se puede resumir en:

- Primero, los objetos son convertidos a valores primitivos, usando [Symbol.toPrimitive()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive), con preferencia hacia `number`
- Si los dos valores son cadenas, serán comparados como tal, con base en los valores de código Unicode que contengan

  - Areglos y objetos: El manual no lo menciona, pero primero se aplica el método `.toString()` para obtener una representación como cadena y comparar
- De lo contrario, Javascript trtará de convertir a valores numéricos:

  - Valores booleanos: Verdadero será convertido a 1 y falso a cero
  - Valor nulo: Será convertido a cero
  - Valor no definido (undefined): Será convertido a NaN (No es un Número)
  - Cadena: Convertida de acuerdo a los valores que contengan, pero será NaN si contiene caracteres no numéricos
- Si cualquiera de los valores es NaN, el resultado siempre será falso
- De lo contrario, serán comparados como valores numéricos

```js
// Operador mayor que y menor que
console.log(5 < '10'); // Verdadero, el segundo elemento se pudo convertir a número
console.log('9' < '10'); // Falso, la comparación se realizó como cadena (9 aparece en tabla de caracteres depués de 1)
console.log('a' < 10); // Falso, la conversión de 'a' es NaN
console.log(10 < '123z'); // Falso, la conversión de '123z' es NaN
console.log(['a', 4] < ['b', 2]); // Verdadero, ambos fueron convertidos a cadena y 'a,4' es menor que 'b,2'
console.log({a: 1} < {b: 2}); // Falso, ambos son iguales [object Object]
console.log({a: 1} > {b: 2}); // Falso, ambos son iguales [object Object]
console.log({a: 1}.toString() == {b: 2}.toString()); // Verdadero, ambos son iguales [object Object]
```

Entonces, en el ejemplo que pones en tu pregunta: Hay un elemento numérico y el otro pudo convertirse también a número sin problema, por eso la evaluación es correcta.

Solo por agregar un poco más sobre el comportamiento de operadores y saber lo que pasa con arreglos y objetos:

El [operador de adición](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) evalúa si los operandos son numéricos (o se pueden convertir a número) para realizar una suma, de lo contrario, los tratará (o forzará) como cadena.

```js
// Operador de adición
console.log('a' + 5); // a5
console.log(5 + '3'); // 53
console.log(false + true); // 1
console.log([1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]); // 1,2,34,5,6
console.log({a:1, b:2} + {c:3, d:4}); // [object Object][object Object]
console.log(1 + 2); // 3
console.log(3.1416 + 6); // 9.1416
console.log(Number(5) + Number('3')); // 8
console.log(Number({a:1, b:2}) + Number({c:3, d:4})); // NaN
```