# Contradicción en javascript? true y false

Tags: javascript

Estaba haciendo un ejercicio esta mañana, tenia que chequear si un objeto tenía una propiedad definida. Después de haberlo resuelto, noté que no me pasaba el test, fui a leer el error y me pareció raro e hice esta prueba en consola, lo cual me dejó mas confundido aún, alguien que me pueda explicar porque pasa esto ?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Javascript, amigo! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador `===` realiza una comparación *estricta*, que siempre producirá `false` cuando el tipo de los valores comparados no es el mismo. Está claro que el valor de `object.name` no es del mismo tipo que `true`.

Por otra parte, el operador unario `!` convierte el valor operado en primitivo booleano y lo niega. En el ejemplo, `!!object.name`, que equivale a `!!"Juan"`, es lo mismo que `!(!object.name)`, luego `!object.name`, según las reglas de conversión a booleano definidas por el estándar (ver tabla), produce `!true` que es `false`; finalmente `!!object.name` equivale a `!false`, es decir, `true`.

[image: Conversión a primitivo booleano]

Answer (score 3):

En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477378/do-while-javascript/477394#477394) se menciona el comportamiento de Javascript al realizar comparaciones y puedes ver más detalles en la documentación sobre [conversión de tipos](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-type-conversion).

Al comparar un valor específico, sin involucrar tipos, todos los valores que no sean [*"falsy"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) van a convertirse en verdadero:

```js
let objeto = { nombre: 'Juan' };

if(objeto.nombre) {
    console.log('Verdadero, porque no se trata de un valor "Falsy"');
}

if(!objeto.nombre) {  // Equivalente a  objeto.nombre == false
    console.log('No entra aquí, porque no es un valor "Falsy"');
}

if(!!objeto.nombre) { // Equivalente a !objeto.nombre == false o objeto.nombre != false
    console.log('Un ! compara si es falso, al tener dos !! invierte el resultado del primero y, por tato, es verdadero');
}


if(objeto.nombre === true) {
    console.log('No entra aquí porque se hace comparación estricta: por tipo y valor');
}


// Si necesitas comprobar que existe la propiedad en el objeto
if(objeto.hasOwnProperty('nombre')) {
    console.log('Sí tiene la propiedad "nombre"');
}

// Verificar que existe y tiene el valor deseado
if(objeto.hasOwnProperty('nombre') && objeto.nombre == 'Juan') {
    console.log('Sí tiene la propiedad "nombre" y es igual a "Juan"');
}

// Verificar que existe y tiene el valor deseado y es del tipo esperado (string)
if(objeto.hasOwnProperty('nombre') && objeto.nombre === 'Juan') {
    console.log('Sí tiene la propiedad "nombre" y es igual a "Juan"');
}

// Que pasa si son comparacion de numeros?

objeto.numero = '100';

// Comparacion NO extrcita

if(objeto.hasOwnProperty('numero') && objeto.numero == 100) {
    console.log('Sí tiene la propiedad "numero" y es similar a "100"');
}

if(objeto.hasOwnProperty('numero') && objeto.numero === 100) {
    console.log('Sí tiene la propiedad "numero" pero no es identica a 100');
}
```

Comment: Hola, te acabo de vandalizar la respuesta agregando 3 ejemplos mas que me gustan usar en estos casos.

Comment: Pero.. pero.. si esa respuesta ES LA RESPUESTA, porque agregar otra respuesta????

Comment: por que la respuesta que ES LA RESPUESTA, me parece que la hacia falta un poco mas para evidenciar un ejemplo de comparacion stricta, pero al mismo tiempo no vi la necesidad de crear otra respuesta adicional... si triby que es el autor no esta de acuerdo puede regresar la edicion al post anterior... NP

Comment: @gbianchi, el caso de la respuesta enlazada no es precisamente de comparación booleana, pero si lo crees conveniente, puedo eliminar esta.

Comment: no para nada.. y fijate que no la marque como duplicada... pero me sono a que dabas la misma respuesta... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Espero poder resolver tu duda te dejo una imagen de como se ejecuto lo que te explico con quokka y te dejo el codigo para que lo pruebes

```js
let objeto = { nombre: "juan" };

objeto.nombre; // en booleano es true ya que 
            //tiene un valor en la propiedad nombre

// si negamos  objeto.nombre nos dara false ya que al tener un valor es true 
//pero no es igual ni estricatmente igual a true
console.log(objeto.nombre); //aqui nos devuelve el valor de la propiedad nombre
console.log(!objeto.nombre); //al negarse se convierte en false
console.log(!!objeto.nombre); // al negarse nuevamente se convierte en true

// el valor nunca sera igual a false ya que es un string ni a true ya que es un string 
//y nunca sera igual a true ni a  false
console.log(objeto.nombre === false);
console.log(objeto.nombre === true);
console.log(objeto.nombre == true);
console.log(objeto.nombre == false);
// esto es equivalente a
console.log("juan" === false);
console.log("juan" === true);
console.log("juan" == true);
console.log("juan" == false);

// el valor nunca sera igual a 0 ya que es un string por eso sera true para el if o para otros fines ya que es un valor
if (objeto.nombre) {
  // si es true se ejecuta si es false no se ejecuta pese a 
  //que objeto.nombre es un string es true pero no es igual ni estrictamente igual a true ni a false
  console.log("hola");
}

//cuando negamos el valor de objeto.nombre nos dara false ya que al tener un valor 
//es true pero no es igual ni estricatmente igual a true
console.log(!objeto.nombre === false);
console.log(!objeto.nombre === true);
console.log(!objeto.nombre == true);
console.log(!objeto.nombre == false);
// lo que seria igual que
console.log(false === false);
console.log(false === true);
console.log(false == true);
console.log(false == false);
// si volvemos a negar el valor pasara de false a true pero no al valor origial "juan"
console.log(!objeto.nombre === false);
console.log(!!objeto.nombre === true);
console.log(!!objeto.nombre == true);
console.log(!objeto.nombre == false);
// lo que seria igual que
console.log(false === false);
console.log(true === true);
console.log(true == true);
console.log(false == false);

// si el valor del objeto estubiera vacio seria equivalente a false pero no igual ni estricatamente igual a false

let objetoVacio = { nombre: "" };
// al ser un objeto vacio es false y en el if no se ejecutara la logica ya que el 
//parametro equivale a false pero no es igual ni estricatamente igual a false

if (objetoVacio.nombre) {
  console.log("hola"); // no se ejecuta
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que es quokka  ???

Comment: un plugin de VScode lo que pongas en el console.log()  saldra en la pantalla del IDE